# Regular expression to get the arguments of a custom function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this custom functions `and()` and `or()`, and I need to get the arguments inside those functions:

```
and(one,two,three) // ["one", "two", "three"]
```

I'm doing it with regex and split:

```
var string = 'and(one,two,three)';
var reg = /(and|or)\((.*)\)/g;
var match = reg.exec(string);
var args = match[2].split(','); // ["one", "two", "three"]
```

But now if I add another function inside the function, like this:

```
and(one,two,or(three,four)) // ["one", "two", "or(three", "four)"]
```

It splits the inside function, because of the `split()`.

I need a regex that returns all the arguments inside the function like this:

```
and(one,two,or(three,four)) // ["one", "two", "or(three,four)"]
```

So I can work with each argument separately. Thanks.

Comment: regular expressions are almost never the right way to parse a recursive grammar.

Comment: Solved it with the duplicated question.

Comment: Yes, `var args = match[2].split(/,\s*(?![^\(]*\))/);` will do.

Comment: Thanks for your help!